# Can not find "Gradual Site Delete" inside my central administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration

I wen to CA->monitoring-> job definition , but i can not find any job named Gradual Site Delete. can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Central Adminstration as administrator -> Monitoring -> Review Job definitions, then sort the jobs according to the web application, select "Schedule type" as daily and search for the "Gradual Site Delete", every web application will have this job.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i did not notice the paging at the end !!